# Cursor has a ring of dots

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Photoshop 19; drawing with the pencil tool or eraser tool the cursor has a ring of dots around it making it hard to see the line.

Can this ring of dots be removed in settings?

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot?

Comment: The "ring of dots" is Adobe's **wait** cursor. It's telling you to wait.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle between standard and precise cursor with the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key

> Tools that have precise cursor capabilities include:
>
> - Eyedropper
> - Healing brushes
> - Patch Tool
> - Red Eye Brushes
> - Rubber Stamp Dodge
> - Burn and Sponge

If you need to change the cursors from the Preferences:

> - Click Photoshop CC on the menu bar and select Preferences.
> - Click on Cursors in the drop-down menu to open a preferences screen.
> - Select Cursors in the left panel of the preferences screen.
> - Select Precise in the Painting Cursors section and Precise in the Other Cursors section.

Answer (score 0):

The "ring of dots" is Adobe's **wait** cursor. It's telling you to wait.

.. at least if this is the "ring of dots" you are referring to...

[image]

<sub>Wouldn't believe how much trouble I had getting that image :)</sub>

Comment: I know what you're going through, sometimes when I try to force my applications to lag/crash and they don't seem to want to... Only when it hurts me the most.

Comment: I Just meant that it's a *cursor* so a screenshot won't capture it... had to actually make a movie to get it.. but yeah when you want to wait.. it seems you don't have to :)